# Uploads in Symfony's var directory not accessible

Tags: symfony, docker, routes, var

I'm trying to upload files into 'var' directory (successfully). But when I want to take this one file from 'var' I only can observe `No route found for "GET /var/uploads/images/....`

**Structure**:

```
 - app
 - bin
 - src
 - var
    - cache
    - logs
    - uploads
       - images
 - vendor
 - web
```

For saving my files I'm using: `'%kernel.project_dir%/var/uploads/images'`

For order to take file: `'/var/uploads/images/' . $fileName;`
Where're my mistake?

P.S. Moreover I try to use volume (I'm using docker) in my docker-compose file like this: `- ./data/cabinet/uploads/images:/data/www/cabinet/var/uploads/images`
 And, unfortunately, no one file didn't copy to this directory. What's wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the document root is pointing to the `web` directory, there's no possibility for path `../var` to be accessible. Either store uploads inside the `web` directory or create a symlink inside it pointing to the `var/data/uploads`:

```
// since I don't know your path tree inside the container
// I assume whole application is installed inside /var/www/html
// and this is the default working directory
docker-compose exec YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME \
ln -rs /var/www/html/var/data web/var
```

Bear in mind that if you are using Apache webserver, the FollowSymLinks option has to be enabled, but most probably is.

As for the second question, most likely you mapped an invalid directory, I guess this should be:

```
// yet again I assume whole application is inside the /var/www/html
./data/cabinet/uploads/images:/var/www/html/data/cabinet/uploads/images
```

Is this some kind of production anyway? If it is not and this is merely a work-in-progress, then you rather should map your whole local directory as container volume. This is how it's usually done in dev mode, so the mapping would be:

```
.:/var/www/html
```

Comment: About symlink: 1st line in docker-compose in voluems is:       - ./data/cabinet/uploads/images:/var/www/html/data/cabinet/uploads/images
and 2st line is: ln -s /var/www/html/web/var /var/www/html/var/data/uploads
yes?

Comment: It's a one-liner. I broke it with that backslash so it's fully visible on the screen and still it's a valid command. You can either execute it via docker-compose or enter the container and execute the command inside it. Also while inside test the symlink with the `cd` that it actually works.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Could you help me one more...My boss wanted that it will be a relative symlink, but I cant understand how to realize it